# Problem with fibonacci function. C++

Tags: c++, function, fibonacci

Should return the `n` place of the array. But instead of the value I'm only getting 0.

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f[100];
    f[0] = 0;
    f[1] = 1;

    for (int i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i-2] + f[i-1];
    }

    return f[n];
}

int main()
{
    cout << fibonacci(3);
    return 0;
}
```

New CODE:

New problem its returning one number further then it should. For example if 'n==7' its returning '13' not '8' like it should.

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f[100] = { 0, 1 };

    for (int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i-2] + f[i-1];
    }

    return f[n-1];
}

int main()
{
    cout << fibonacci(7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could shorten your array initialization to `int f[100] = { 0, 1 }` and it will initialize all the other elements to 0 automatically. Also, you could make the array static (and add a static counter of the last calculated position) so you don't have to recalculate values you already know every time. Just FYI

Comment: @ Chris thanks this is helpful i will make sure and do this.

Comment: NOTE: There is an integer overflow in your code for `fibonacci(48)`. Use `uint64_t` instead of `int` to get correct values upto `n==94`. http://codepad.org/ApUew5IY

Comment: you could cache the results in the `f` array if your measurements show that a program spends too much time in the `fibonacci()` function http://codepad.org/Ve7pvSjP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you never set `f[n]`, you only go up to `i < n`, that is, `i == n-1`.
try returning `f[n-1]`

EDIT: as Chris Lutz pointed out my answer is no good as it would give an invalid result if you called `fibonacci(0)`

Like many have answered already, the best solution is to loop until `i <= n`
Unless, of course, you want `fibonacci(3)` to return the 3rd element in the fibonacci sequence and not the 4th, in which case `fibonacci(0)` wouldn't really make sense, and the right return value would be `f[n-1]`... still the `n==0` case should be handled somehow, as should the `n<0`and the `n>100` cases.

you can return `f[n-1]` as long as you check for the right boundaries:

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f[100] = { 0, 1 };

    if ((n <= 0) || (n > 100))
        return -1;//return some invalid number to tell the caller that he used bad input

    for (int i=2; i < n; i++) // you can use i < n here
    {
        f[i] = f[i-2] + f[i-1];
    }

    return f[n-1];
}
```

Comment: -1 right problem, wrong solution. `fibonacci(0)` should return a valid value.

Comment: @filipe - If you @me SO will notify me so I can retract my downvote before the vote-changing time limit expires. (I just happened to check a minute after your edit, so you got lucky this time.)

Comment: @filipe this is what i do i <= n but i cant return n-1 for the problems you have said above. So im stuck.

Comment: @Chris Lutz like this? huh, I didn't know that. I'll use that from now on, thanks. =)

Comment: @filipe the thing is n==0 is a correct input because f[n] when n=0 is f[0] which is = to 0 if that made any scene at all.

Comment: @Alec well, if `fibonacci(0)` should return the first element in the sequence (0), then `fibonacci(1)` would return the second element (1) and not the first, and so forth, including `fibonacci(7)` returning the 8th element (13) and not the 7th (8).

Comment: @Alec I would say that if `fibonacci(1)` should return the first element, then `fibonacci(0)` would be bad input, as there is no "0th" element in the sequence. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @filipe I agree this is what i shal do. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: NOTE: There is integer overflow in your code for `fibonacci(48)`. Use `uint64_t` instead of `int` to get correct values upto n==94. http://codepad.org/ApUew5IY

Answer (score 4):

Your loop termination condition is wrong.  Since this is homework perhaps you can work out why.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize the n-th value of the array. You return f[n] but only initialize up to n-1.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that you test for `i < n` (where `n == 3` in your example call), but you return `f[3]` which has not been set to anything.  You are 'lucky' that you're getting zeroes rather than random garbage.

Change the '`<`' to '`<=`'.

---

#### Working Code #1

Retaining the full size array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f[100] = { 0, 1 };

    if (n < 0 || n > 100)
        return -1;
    else if (n < 2)
        return f[n];

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i-2] + f[i-1];
        //cout << "f[" << i << "] = " << f[i] << endl;
    }

    return f[n];
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << "fib(" << i << ") = " << fibonacci(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample Output #1

```
fib(0) = 0
fib(1) = 1
fib(2) = 1
fib(3) = 2
fib(4) = 3
fib(5) = 5
fib(6) = 8
fib(7) = 13
```

#### Working Code #2

This uses an array of size 3, at the cost of a lot of modulo operations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f[3] = { 0, 1, 0 };

    if (n < 0 || n > 100)
        return -1;
    else if (n < 2)
        return f[n];

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        f[i%3] = f[(i-2)%3] + f[(i-1)%3];
        //cout << "f[" << i << "] = " << f[i%3] << endl;
    }

    return f[n%3];
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << "fib(" << i << ") = " << fibonacci(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the same output - so there is no point in repeating it.

#### Working Code #3

Avoiding arrays and modulo operations:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f0 = 0;
    int f1 = 1;

    if (n < 0 || n > 46)
        return -1;
    else if (n == 0)
        return f0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return f1;

    int fn;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int fn = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = fn;
        //cout << "f[" << i << "] = " << fn << endl;
    }

    return f1;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = -2; i < 50; i++)
        cout << "fib(" << i << ") = " << fibonacci(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The limit 46 is empirically determined as correct for 32-bit signed integers.

#### Example Output #3

```
fib(-2) = -1
fib(-1) = -1
fib(0) = 0
fib(1) = 1
fib(2) = 1
fib(3) = 2
fib(4) = 3
fib(5) = 5
fib(6) = 8
fib(7) = 13
fib(8) = 21
fib(9) = 34
fib(10) = 55
fib(11) = 89
fib(12) = 144
fib(13) = 233
fib(14) = 377
fib(15) = 610
fib(16) = 987
fib(17) = 1597
fib(18) = 2584
fib(19) = 4181
fib(20) = 6765
fib(21) = 10946
fib(22) = 17711
fib(23) = 28657
fib(24) = 46368
fib(25) = 75025
fib(26) = 121393
fib(27) = 196418
fib(28) = 317811
fib(29) = 514229
fib(30) = 832040
fib(31) = 1346269
fib(32) = 2178309
fib(33) = 3524578
fib(34) = 5702887
fib(35) = 9227465
fib(36) = 14930352
fib(37) = 24157817
fib(38) = 39088169
fib(39) = 63245986
fib(40) = 102334155
fib(41) = 165580141
fib(42) = 267914296
fib(43) = 433494437
fib(44) = 701408733
fib(45) = 1134903170
fib(46) = 1836311903
fib(47) = -1
fib(48) = -1
fib(49) = -1
```

Comment: New problem its returning one number further then it should. For example if 'n==7' its returning '13' not '8' like it should.

Comment: what about for case n=0 though?

Comment: @Alec: I think that F(7) = 13 when you specify F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1; see the example outputs above.

Answer (score 2):

n is the index that is never reached in your version. You just need to replace the **<** with **<=** in your for loop conditional. (You never assigned f[n] because n was never reached by the loop and so you got back a default value.)

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    int f[100];
    f[0] = 0;
    f[1] = 1;

    for (int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i-2] + f[i-1];
    }

    return f[n];
}

int main()
{
    cout << fibonacci(3);
    return 0;
}
```

And you don't need an array to perform the fib sequence by the way. Just use two variables and reassign them in the loop. Something like this:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;

for (int i=2; i<=n; i++)
{
    b = a + b;
    a = b;
}

return b;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the call `fibonacci(3)`, your for loop (inside the fibonacci function) goes until `i < 3`...

It means that the last assigment is `f[2]`. Not `f[3]` as expected (which is the value you return).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean 
return f[n-1];

I guess your compiler has set the array f[100]  to 0?

Looks like the other guy has the right answer....