# How to generate 10 terms of Fibonacci series in c++?

Tags: c++

In mathematics, the Fibonacci numbers are the numbers in the following integer sequence, called the Fibonacci sequence, and characterized by the fact that every number after the first two is the sum of the two preceding ones. 
 

  1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, ... 
 
I really tried,  but I couldn't mentally get it into code, Here is mine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
cout <<"Fibonacci series " << endl;

int arr[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         arr[i] = i;

         arr[i+2] = arr[i]+arr[i+1];

}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;



return 0;
}
```

What should I do to represent 10 terms of Fibonacci series?

Comment: Search SO before posting. Fibonacci is _SO_ common, you find code in any language you want.

Comment: This `arr[i+2]` and this `[i+1]` fails badly if `i` gets bigger than `7` or`8`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I use arrays, I want to get the idea by using arrays.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Of course, I searched and I saw all of them in c++, nothing of them was using arrays.

Comment: Well then you must have overlooked this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349785/7505395

Comment: @PatrickArtner I didn't see it, now you can consider it duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. And can be done can be done with a few tweaks in your code

Your first `for` loop will produce an out of bounds error as in the 9th iteration (i = 8) you will be accessing a non existent arr[10].

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout <<"Fibonacci series " << endl;

    int arr[10];
    arr[0] = arr [1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i-1]+arr[i-2];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

In the above code you can replace 10 with any other number and it will produce that many numbers in the series. Replace the 10 in array declaration, and both the for loop end condition.

You can also do this without an array and only one loop if you just need to print the series:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout <<"Fibonacci series " << endl;
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    cout << a << endl << b << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ((a<b) ? a : b ) = a + b;
        cout << ((a>b) ? a : b ) << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

In the `for` loop the smallest of the two number is selected and is assigned the sum of the two no's. Then the largest of the two is printed which is the number which was just modified.

eg:

Output initial : 1 1

**1:** i = 2; a = 1; b = 1; the smallest of the two (here b as `a < b` fails) is assigned the sum of the two values which is the next number in the series, b = 2. Now the larger number (which is the number just modified as `a+b > b`) is printed. output : 1 1 2

**2:** i =3; a = 1; b = 2; the smaller (now a) is assigned the sum (3), a = 3;Now the larger number (which is the number just modified as `a+b > b`) is printed. output : 1 1 2 3

and so on

**EDIT:** For your comment to take `n` as user input, you better use std::vector or a pointer. Really recommend the former as it is a lot less mess and less prone to help in "shooting yourself in the foot".

The code will look like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout <<"Fibonacci series " << endl;

    vector<int> arr;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter no to print \n";
    cin >> n;
    arr.push_back(1);
    arr.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
        arr.push_back(arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

And with pointers :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout <<"Fibonacci series " << endl;

    int* arr;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter no to print \n";
    cin >> n;
    arr = new int [n];
    arr[0] = arr [1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i-1]+arr[i-2];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << endl;

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** Thanks @Xam

Comment: @user4581301 where?

Comment: Pulling comment. bad math on my part.

Comment: Thanks, for n array elements it needs a constant, why I can't cin>> a constant?

Comment: An array needs to know the size at compile time and therefore requires a compile time constant and cannot be taken from the user

Comment: @WARhead In some IDE's like codeblocks we can take arr[variable];. But I have been retold by others that I should do this.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Harris I dont know about that but usually a constexpr declared variable can only declare size of an array

Comment: @WARhead Can you explain your second solution?

Comment: You forget to delete your array: `delete arr[]`. Btw, +1 for using `<vector>`.